# No available source for Ninject bootstrapper

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ninject-2, ninject-extensions

I have been added Ninject Mvc Extensions via nuget to my project and it has been put NinjectMVC3 file into App_Start folder. If i stepping into my source codes, "No available source" page appear front of me.

Problem is that i can not access next step into code line. I have to find next step in my own code and put breakpoint.

It is looking for NinjectDependencyResolver.cs but there is no such a file in current path as it has been show in below information.

Below is source file information from Visual Studio.

```
Locating source for 'c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectDependencyResolver.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {c4 f8 b4 46 45 cb f8 1c c7 74 29 b9 70 9f 2b 24}
The file 'c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectDependencyResolver.cs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectDependencyResolver.cs'...
Looking in the projects for 'c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectDependencyResolver.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmf敤楦楮楴湯祜畯摲晥湩瑩'...
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectDependencyResolver.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectDependencyResolver.cs'.
```

How can i get rid of this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this is a problem. This standard behaviour when you don't have source code for the dll you are trying to debug. Either build ninject from source or ignore the warning.

Comment: You can open stack trace window, see what is in the stack, and double click on the stack frame you are interested in. Then put you breakpoint at the required line in your code near this stack frame.